# Big-query for remove @ImSRK in the tweets string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am doing sentiment analysis on Twitter using Google cloud. In my bigtable, I have tweets from thousand of people. I want to remove @NarendraModi from the tweets. Could you please help me out to find big-query for that.  For example
@NarendraModi congratulation sir
In the above tweets, I want to remove @narendramodi from the string. There is a single space after @Narendramodi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL using either REPLACE or REGEXP_REPLACE

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '@NarendraModi congratulation sir' tweet
)
SELECT REPLACE(tweet, '@NarendraModi ', ''),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(tweet, r'@NarendraModi\s*', ''),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(tweet, r'@\w+\s+', '')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

the output is

```
Row f0_                 f1_                 f2_  
1   congratulation sir  congratulation sir  congratulation sir
```

> I have two patterns left 1) "@somename:" and 2) "@somename."

below addresses additional patterns

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '@NarendraModi congratulation sir' tweet UNION ALL
  SELECT '@NarendraModi. congratulation sir' tweet UNION ALL
  SELECT '@NarendraModi: congratulation sir' tweet 

)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tweet, r'@\w+[:.\s]*', '')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   congratulation sir   
2   congratulation sir   
3   congratulation sir
```

Comment: I have lots different tweets like @narendraModi

Comment: That was not clear from your original question - anyway - i just added third line that does replacement for any @xyz

Comment: @ Mikhali Berlyant I am running this query in Big query google cloud platform.

Comment: my answer IS for BigQuery! if you think it does not work for you - please be specific what exactly and how does not work so we can further help you

Comment: Hi there, Sorry for wasting your time. I was doing it wrong. I forgot to write regex. Works like a charm now. Thanks a million!!

Comment: @ Mikhail Berlyant Hi, sorry to bother you again. your query has worked great. However, I have two patterns left 1) "@somename:" and 2) "@somename."

Comment: the way SO works is you ask questions we answer them. I fully answered your current question! you should accept it and if you still have question - feel free to post new one - try to formulate this new one such that it will cover fully your case. meantime  - i added those patterns in my answer - if you will have more questions - please respect rules and post new question

Comment: Thanks a lot and I am new to stack overflow, so didn't know how ir works. I will keep in mind to post a new question. Thanks Again.